# Adding date sent (from mail) to row in Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that makes an pdf from a Spreadsheet and sends an email to the emailaddress in that Spreadsheet. When the pdf is sent the script automaticly adds a row to another Spreadsheet with name, emailaddress and URL related to that pdf thats's created and sent.

Everything works perfect so far.

The only thing I can't figure out is how I can add the date sent (from the email) to the Spreadsheet with name, emailaddress and URL related to that pdf thats's created and sent.

I have no clue how I can find the date of the email sent. 
I tried to explain the script as much as possible.

```
function createPDF() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.alert( // pop up to ask if the spreadsheet should be saved as pdf
      "Opslaan als PDF?",
      "Sla " +sheet1.getName()+ "_" + sheet1.getRange("A12").getValue() +".pdf op als PDF", // shows the name of the pdf that will be created
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (result == ui.Button.OK) {
   var docblob =         
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs("application/pdf"); 
    docblob.setName(sheet1.getName() + "_" + sheet1.getRange("A12").getValue() + ".pdf"); // combines name of spreadsheet and student to create name for pdf
    var file = DriveApp.createFile(docblob);
    ui.alert(sheet1.getName() + "_" + sheet1.getRange("A12").getValue() + " is beschikbaar via deze link: " + file.getUrl()); // url to created pdf
  } else {
    ui.alert("Opslaan als .pdf is niet gelukt");
  }

  // the following code add just created pdf and another (already excisting) pdf to email
  var OOKnaam = file.getName(); // pdf just created
  var bijlage1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName(OOKnaam); 
  var bijlage2 =     
DriveApp.getFilesByName("Algemene_Voorwaarden.pdf"); // add the other pdf

  var defMessage = "message to student";
  var subject = "Je OOK & POK";
  var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange("A13").getValue(); // gets the emailaddress added in spreadsheet to send mail


  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // pop up with confirmation

  var result2 = ui.alert(
      "Versturen naar "+emailAddress+ "?",
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (result2 == ui.Button.OK) {
     MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, defMessage, {
         replyTo: "email@email.nl",
         name: "name of sender",
         attachments: [bijlage1.next(), bijlage2.next()]

       })
   ui.alert("De email is verstuurd naar "+emailAddress);
   } else {
   ui.alert("Email versturen is mislukt");
   }

// following code adds email, file name and url to another spreadsheet
  var ontvangenSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID);
  var eMailVoorReminder = sheet1.getRange("A13").getValue();

    data = [ 
      eMailVoorReminder,
      file.getName(),
      file.getUrl(),
    ];

    ontvangenSheet.appendRow(data);
}
```

I'm not looking for the answer right away. I would like to know where to start or look so that I can figure it out myself.

**Edit:**
I added a timestamp to my script:

```
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "dd-MM-yyyy' om 'HH:mm"); 

    data = [ 
      eMailVoorReminder,
      file.getName(),
      file.getUrl(),
      formattedDate,
   ];

ontvangenSheet.appendRow(data);
```

It does add a timestamp to the added row but it even does it when the e-mail is not sent (canceled). So not completely satisfied with this solution so far.

Comment: Look into how to search your sent emails and grab it from there, or how to add a timestamp using apps script.

Comment: @ross Thanks. One thing I forgot to mention is that there will be different users for this script. So searching my emails will not work I think. I will check te timestamp option!

Comment: Sorry - meant searching whoever runs the script's sent emails. Might seem pretty intrusive to some users though, just time stamping it is probably your better option.